# Images not resizing correctly in chrome full screen

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, google-chrome

this is my first post so excuse my lack of information and flow of things.

The images on [this](http://milkhoneymold.com) site that im working on are not resizing correctly in chrome; max window size. i see that the images dont want to stretch but they are far too big. I built the site in dreamweaver so it shows everything working fine on its end but in chrome its not correct.

html img 1

```
<section class="intro">
    <img src="hglogo.jpg">  
</section>
```

css img 1

```
.intro img {    
width: 100%;
max-height: 100%;   
}
```

html img 2

```
<section id="bio">
        <ul class="img-list">
            <li>
                <img src="img/bg4.jpg"/>
                   <span class="text-content"><span><h2>Who Is Henry?</h2>
                     ...
```

css img 2

```
#bio img {
width: 100%;
max-height: 100%;
}
```

I would appreciate any help thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

instead of this:

```css
#bio img {
  width: 100%;
  max-height: 100%;
}
```

change to this:

```css
#bio img {
  max-width: 100%;
  height:auto;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

That's because of the `max-heigth: 100%`. Putting this will make your image stop scaling when it's at 100% of his height-size. Replace it by `height: auto` or simply remove it in order to make it work.